# How can I use a mermaid Flowchart LR for describing a Pyhton code line?

Tags: python, diagram, mermaid

I want to describe a python code line in a quarto document for further description with a mermaid flowchart LR diagram.

It should look like this:

[image]

The Pyhton codeline is this:

```
tfidf_text_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=list(stopwords), min_df=5, max_df=0.7)
```

I try to split the code line in a mermaid code chunk:

````
```{mermaid}
   flowchart LR
       tfidf_text_vectorizer --> TfidfVectorizer(
       TfidfVectorizer( --> stop_words
       stop_words --> =list(stopwords),
       =list(stopwords), --> min_df=5, 
       min_df=5, --> max_df=0.7)
```
````

But I receive the error in VS Code: undefinded.

Can I describe a code line with mermaid. If yes, how can I do this?

PS: Are there any other solutions for describe a code line in a quarto document?

Comment: I think it would help if you hand sketched an approximation of the outcome you want.  Do you want a bunch of nested squares? Or do you want something like a `%>%` or `|>` sequence?

Comment: Also <http://mermaid.live> is a good place to try out building up the image.

Comment: Hello @jameshowison I added a picture. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to create a flowchart in mermaid that understands how to parse elements from any specific coding language, as it seems you are trying to do here.

I have tried putting together something similar to what I "think" you are trying to do, see [Live Editor](https://%5B!%5B%5D(https://mermaid.ink/img/pako:eNptUctuwyAQ_BW0p0ZyLNsxtkFNL80lh54S9dC6spCBBMlAhHGeyr-XOG3VQzjNzL5m2Qu0lguggJDs7KHdMufRelEbdH-v1uyF8581_CDEUGu7TrReWRPHcQ1f0-mLl4rLxoujb_YhZJ06CxeKHurz9U19_-NPvbe75mAd79Ecdar3ozIKkwhpZRou5_g_CiORZscbS-JyEkz8OX448jkULOXKO2U2wdZShjX6kd1XgAi0cJopHr7icusVvG-FFjXQALmQbOh8DbW5hlQ2eLs6mRaod4OIYNhx5sVCsY1jGqhkXR_UHTMf1urfpECBXuAINC2TmJSzqkgLks9mmOQRnIBmZRYTkpc4IWWBiwxfIziPDZIYJ2le5UVWVZgUeZpGILgKu73djzfe8PoNoreVCQ?type=png)%5D(https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNptUctuwyAQ_BW0p0ZyLNsxtkFNL80lh54S9dC6spCBBMlAhHGeyr-XOG3VQzjNzL5m2Qu0lguggJDs7KHdMufRelEbdH-v1uyF8581_CDEUGu7TrReWRPHcQ1f0-mLl4rLxoujb_YhZJ06CxeKHurz9U19_-NPvbe75mAd79Ecdar3ozIKkwhpZRou5_g_CiORZscbS-JyEkz8OX448jkULOXKO2U2wdZShjX6kd1XgAi0cJopHr7icusVvG-FFjXQALmQbOh8DbW5hlQ2eLs6mRaod4OIYNhx5sVCsY1jGqhkXR_UHTMf1urfpECBXuAINC2TmJSzqkgLks9mmOQRnIBmZRYTkpc4IWWBiwxfIziPDZIYJ2le5UVWVZgUeZpGILgKu73djzfe8PoNoreVCQ))